# How do I add a scroll view without moving my other views?

Tags: android, scrollview

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="I like to go out more than staying home."
                    android:textSize="10.5dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Do you tend to over analyze everything, all the time?"
                    android:textSize="10.5dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="You&apos;ve made most of your decisions based on how you feel."
                    android:textSize="10.5dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="You use past experiences to guide your decisions."
                    android:textSize="10.5dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>




        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Submit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/personalitytype"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Personality Type"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

</TableLayout>
```

A picture of my applicaton can viewed here : http://tinypic.com/r/2uy1t3d/5

Hello, I'd like to add a scroll view to my questions in my application.  This would include the TextViews and Spinners but not the Submit button on the bottom or the TextView below it.  I understand you'd have to mess with the weight, but i'm not getting good results.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Button and TextViews below it to remain at the bottom, try putting everything in a RelativeLayout, wrapping your Buttons and TextViews in a LinearLayout and aligning it to the parent's bottom.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="I like to go out more than staying home."
                android:textSize="10.5dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Do you tend to over analyze everything, all the time?"
                android:textSize="10.5dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="You&apos;ve made most of your decisions based on how you feel."
                android:textSize="10.5dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="You use past experiences to guide your decisions."
                android:textSize="10.5dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Submit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/personalitytype"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Personality Type"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Full disclaimer: Code not tested.